# Error uploading shinydashboard to shiny.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I´ve built an app in `Shiny` using `shinydashboardplus`. Although the app runs fine locally when I try to deploy the app on shiny.io using:

`rsconnect::deployApp(here::here('Directory')`

I get the following error:

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 5, column 10

Inside my app I'm I'm calling a .Rmd with

`withMathJax(includeMarkdown("include.Rmd")`

which header is this one

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ""
output: html_document
  mathjax: "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
runtime: shiny
---
```

I think this may be causing the problem

Comment: I suspect some dependancy missing, try running your app with another R session or reboot and try the same

Comment: @PorkChop Thanks a lot! I've made an edit to the original question. Thanks for answering so fast.